# Preventing the "Coordinate Reference System Selector" query/window after processing.run()

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I want to convert a DXF with python/ogr2ogr.
Unfortunately **QGIS 2.99** always asks for the CRS.

```
QSettings().value('/Projections/defaultBehavior')
'useGlobal'
QSettings().value('/Projections/layerDefaultCrs')
'EPSG:25833'

processing.run('gdal:convertformat',{'INPUT':'d:/tar/mytest.dxf','OPTIONS':'','OUTPUT': 'c:/../x.shp'})
```

Without the processing-plugin the following code also produce a CRS Window

```
from processing.tools import dataobjects
parameters={'INPUT':'d:/tar/mytest.dxf','OPTIONS':'','OUTPUT': 'c:/../x.shp'}
context=dataobjects.createContext(None)
alg = QgsApplication.processingRegistry().createAlgorithmById('gdal:convertformat')
alg.checkParameterValues(parameters, context)
```

Is there a way to prevent the "Coordinate Reference System Selector" query/window?

I need this code for my plugin "**Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter**". This command is called 3-5 times per DXF. If there are 5 DXF-s, the dialog window appears 15-25 times. The query of the CRS is absolutely superfluous, since no transformation should take place and also no projection file must be written.

The code for **QGIS 2.xx**

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat','d:/tar/mytest.dxf‌​',0,None,'d:/tar/xx.‌​shp')
```

works without Problems (without window)

Comment: I'm not answering your question. But side note, I think in QGIS 3, you should use QgsSettings instead of QSettings.

Answer (score 1):

for disable this dialog using QGIS 3 only need this,

```
settings = QSettings()
settings.setValue('/Projections/defaultBehavior', '')
```

and if you want disable and enable after execute your code,

```
prjSetting3= settings.value('/Projections/defaultBehavior')
settings.setValue('/Projections/defaultBehavior', '')

......

settings.setValue('/Projections/defaultBehavior', prjSetting3)
```

Comment: Just a comment to note this should work on QGIS 2 also.

Comment: **No, that does not work.** Also with this code comes the CRS window

`settings = QSettings() 
settings.setValue('/Projections/defaultBehavior', '') 
processing.run('gdal:convertformat',{'INPUT':'d:/tar/mytest.dxf','OPTIONS':'','OUTPUT': 'c:/../x.shp'})`

Comment: Oops!sorry!this code disable the load crs dialog but not the input dialog